# Validation not working in mongoose in node with Mongo

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have created a schema for user and add validation

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    email:{type:String ,required : true, unique: true, lowercase: true ,validate : emailValidators},
    password:{type:String ,required : true ,validate:validPassword}

});
```

Validate password function

```
let validaEmailChecker =(email)=>{
    if(!email){
        return false;
    }else{
        const regExp = new 
        RegExp(/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/);
return regExp.test(email)

    }
}
```

Validate password function

```
let validPassword =(password)=>{
    if(!password){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        const regExp = new RegExp( /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{5,10}$/);
        return regExp.test(password)

    }
}
```

To call user function use

```
 user.save((err) => { 
   // use save or nor
}
```

User save function not calling after adding validation function in schema in second property
only work when use with email validator when add password validator add it not work

Comment: please post few of your email & password input test cases

Answer (score 0):

You have set `emailValidators` as validating function for the `email` field, while the function you're showing is named `validaEmailChecker`. Change one of those to match the other, like it is with the `password` field.